# verify the date is valid or not in hive?

Tags: date, hadoop, hive, hiveql

i have date column in the format yyyyMMdd. i want to check whether the date is valid or not.
in informatica, the function is available as `CASE WHEN IS_DATE(TO_CHAR(DT),'YYYYMMDD') = 0 THEN TO_DATE('99991231','YYYYMMDD') ELSE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DT),'YYYYMMDD') END AS EFF_DT`

as in hive alternative to 'is_date' function is not available, how to achieve the same in hive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regexp:

```
case when regexp_extract(date_column,'(19|20)[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])',0) = '' 
     then 'not valid date' 
     else 'valid date' 
end
```

Edit regular expression according to your date requirements.

You can use a macro:

```
create temporary macro isDate(s string)
case when regexp_extract(s,'(19|20)[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])',0) = '' 
         then false 
         else true 
    end;
```

Then use it in your SQL:

```
select * from table where isDate(date_col);
```

For `yyyy-MM-dd` format you can use `cast(date_col as date)`:

```
create temporary macro isDate(s string)
case cast(s as date) is not null then true else false end
```

Comment: This regex matches on 20180230, but February 30th does not exist.

Comment: @Narvarth Sure, this check is quite simple and does not check all cases. Even Hive date() does not check for this case. You can apply more complex regex: https://rgxdb.com/r/2V9BOC58

Comment: @Narvarth To check everything you will need to load calendar and do a lookup

Answer (score 0):

Assume you date format yyyy-MM-dd i.e 2018-07-20

To get all the invalid

```
Select required_column_name from table_name where cast(date_column_name as date) is NULL;
```

To get all the valid

```
Select required_column_name from table_name where cast(date_column_name as date) is not NULL;
```

Comment: Casting doesn't seem to be reliable: `SELECT CAST('20180228' AS DATE)` returns `NULL` because of the missing hiphens, and `SELECT CAST('2018-02-30' AS DATE)` returns `2018-03-02`.